# Convert binary numbers to byte with a GNU Core Utility?

Tags: bash, unix, binary, byte, bit

How do I convert the string `01100110 01101111 01101111` to `foo` in Unix? Which of the GNU Core Utilities does that if any? I know how to do it in Python, but it must be possible with another tool, no? The tools `hexdump` and `od` don't seem to do the trick.

This tool does what I want:
http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/convert-text-to-binary/

Comment: Is using the shell OK? Are you using bash?

Comment: @kabanus Yes, shell is perfect. Yes, I'm using bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `printf` built-in and `bash`:

```
for x in 01100110 01101111 01101111; do printf "%b" $(printf '\\x%x' $((2#$x))); done; echo
```

results in `foo` as expected. Breakdown:

1. `$((2#$x))` converts what's in 'x' from binary to decimal.
2. the `\\x%x` converts the decimal to hexa, add adding a `\x` at the beginning so the next `printf` sees it and treats it like an hexa.
3. `%b` printf - print hexa as character.

Comment: for performance passing through variable assignment avoids launching a sub shell : `printf -v x %x $((2#$x)); printf '\x'$x;` and it's much faster

Comment: an example to compare `time { for ((i=0;i<100;i+=1)); do printf -v x %x $((2#01010101)); printf '\x'$x; done; echo; }` and `time { for ((i=0;i<100;i+=1)); do printf "%b" $(printf '\\x%x' $((2#01010101))); done; echo; }`